# Is there any way to return HTML in a PHP function? (without building the return value as a string)

Tags: php, string, templating

I have a PHP function that I'm using to output a standard block of HTML. It currently looks like this:

```
<?php function TestBlockHTML ($replStr) { ?>
    <html>
    <body><h1> <?php echo ($replStr) ?> </h1>
    </html>
<?php } ?>
```

I want to return (rather than echo) the HTML inside the function. Is there any way to do this without building up the HTML (above) in a string?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You can use a [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), which supports variable interpolation, making it look fairly neat:

```
function TestBlockHTML ($replStr) {
return <<<HTML
    <html>
    <body><h1>{$replStr}</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
HTML;
}
```

Pay close attention to the warning in the manual though - the closing line must not contain any whitespace, so can't be indented.

Comment: Also the <<<HTML heredoc identifier must not be indented, that is if it does not have something such as "return" in front of it.

Comment: it can be indented as much as you like, but should have a newline right after the identifier.

Comment: You can avoid braces if the var is non into an array:

<h1>$replStr</h1>

or

<h1>{$array['var]}</h1>

Answer (score 101):

Yes, there is: you can capture the `echo`ed text using [`ob_start`](http://php.net/ob_start):

```
<?php function TestBlockHTML($replStr) {
    ob_start(); ?>
    <html>
    <body><h1><?php echo($replStr) ?></h1>
    </html>
<?php
    return ob_get_clean();
} ?>
```

Comment: Exactly, this way syntax is highlighted and key words are colored as they would being normal HTML, other than being content in a string. Definitely a better answer for maintainability, which should always come first

Comment: Why would you use the output buffer when this seems to work fine?

`<?php function outputHTML($string) { ?>
 <h1><?php echo $string; ?></h1>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolar</p>
<? } ?>

<?php outputHTML('A is for Apple'); ?>
<?php outputHTML('B is for Ball'); ?>`

Comment: @Joren Because that's explicitly what the OP doesn't want.

Comment: Ok, so if you wanted to echo it, my example would be the way to go?

Comment: @Joren Yes, essentially.

Comment: This is perfect. You can even include echo statements after ob_start and it is included in ob_get_clean()'s output. I am writing modules for a third-party script, and it forces you to put all of the output for the page into a get() function. This is a lifesaver.

Answer (score 19):

This may be a sketchy solution, and I'd appreciate anybody pointing out whether this is a bad idea, since it's not a standard use of functions. I've had some success getting HTML out of a PHP function without building the return value as a string with the following:

```
function noStrings() {
    echo ''?>
        <div>[Whatever HTML you want]</div>
    <?php;
}
```

The just 'call' the function:

```
noStrings();
```

And it will output:

```
<div>[Whatever HTML you want]</div>
```

Using this method, you can also define PHP variables within the function and echo them out inside the HTML.

Comment: /mindblown can you explain why this works when all else failed?

Comment: this works fine without `echo`, just `?> html <?php`. Check the [fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/ejs4-r3ua)

Comment: At least in PHP 8.1.12 on Windows, keep in mind that you need whitespace after the `<?php` on line 4. Without it, PHP throws error `Unclosed '{' on line 4`. Also note that this SO question technically asks for a way to `return` output, but this solution `echo`s it!

Answer (score 9):

Create a template file and use a template engine to read/update the file. It will increase your code's maintainability in the future as well as separate display from logic.

An example using [Smarty](http://smarty.net):

**Template File**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head><title>{$title}</title></head>
<body>{$string}</body>
</html>
```

**Code**

```
function TestBlockHTML(){
  $smarty = new Smarty();
  $smarty->assign('title', 'My Title');
  $smarty->assign('string', $replStr);
  return $smarty->render('template.tpl');
}
```

Comment: Winging some old PHP code. This is solid, thanks! I had to use Smarty's `display` method instead of `render`.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do is is to use [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and have a template HTML page

TEMPLATE PAGE

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head><title>$title</title></head>
<body>$content</body>
</html>
```

PHP Function

```
function YOURFUNCTIONNAME($url){

$html_string = file_get_contents($url);
return $html_string;

}
```

Comment: This is the closest to what I'm looking for. @Cayde 6, do you think theres a way to have a single file 'template.php', containing both the php function and html? So then anywhere in my site, I just 'require_once('template.php')', then call echo the function wherever I need that html to appear. In the YOURFUNCTIONNAME($url), would the $url would need to be itself? How can we do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just use this:

```
<?
function TestHtml() { 
# PUT HERE YOU PHP CODE
?>
<!-- HTML HERE -->

<? } ?>
```

to get content from this function , use this :

```
<?= file_get_contents(TestHtml()); ?>
```

That's it :)

Comment: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty. How should this suppose to work?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have to rely on a third party tool you can use this technique:

```
function TestBlockHTML($replStr){
  $template = 
   '<html>
     <body>
       <h1>$str</h1>
     </body>
   </html>';
 return strtr($template, array( '$str' => $replStr));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Template File

```
<h1>{title}</h1>
<div>{username}</div>
```

### PHP

```
if (($text = file_get_contents("file.html")) === false) {
    $text = "";
}

$text = str_replace("{title}", "Title Here", $text);
$text = str_replace("{username}", "Username Here", $text);
```

then you can echo $text as string