# Return HTML from PHP function

Tags: php, html, string

I have a PHP function that I'm using to output a standard block of HTML

```
 <?php function test () { ?>
 echo(" <html>
    <body><h1> HELLO </h1> </body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

but i see the string of HTML and not the page 
I have see this 
[Is there any way to return HTML in a PHP function? (without building the return value as a string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528445/is-there-any-way-to-return-html-in-a-php-function-without-building-the-return)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use SLIM framework change the content type:

```
$app->contentType('application/json');
```

to:

```
$app->contentType('text/html');
```

then use render function of slim instance with specific template or simply echo html string

Answer (score 2):

you have to do

```
<?php

function text() {
    echo '<html><body><h1>Hello</h1></body></html>';
}

?>
```

But in addition this is not the base valid structure of a page. You're missing the `<head />` tag.

Comment: This method not found I use SLIM and return the string and not the page.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php 
function test () 
    { 
      echo '<html><body><h1> HELLO </h1> </body></html>' ;
    } 

?>
```

Comment: not found i use Slim and see only the string of html

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

function text() {
    return '<html><body><h1>Hello</h1></body></html>';
}

?>
```

and where you need it just:

```
<?php echo text(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```
<?php

    function test()
    {
       $html = '<html>';
       $html .= '<body>';
       $html .= '<h1>Hello</h1>';
       $html .= '</body>';
       $html .= '</html>';

       echo $html;
         //or
       return $html;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you have something called heredoc which lets you write large amounts of text from within PHP, but without the need to constantly escape things. The syntax is `<<<EOT [text here] EOT;`

So in your case you can have the function return the text like this

```
function test() {
    return <<<EOT
        <html>
            <body><h1>HELLO</h1></body>
        </html>
    EOT;
 }
```

Then just call function test to get the contents

```
echo test();
```