# HTML code called from php method

Tags: php, html

I made a register login system in object-oriented PHP. I need the HTML code to be callable from a PHP method.

Here is the View.php class:

```
<?php
class View{

public function createLoginUI(){
    ?>
    <html>
    <title></title>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <form>
        Email:<input type="text" name="mail">
        Pass:<input type="text" name="pass">
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"><br>
        <a href="?regist" >Regist</a>

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
}

public function createRegistUI()
{
    ?>
    <html>
    <title></title>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <form>
        Name:<input type="text" name="name">
        Email:<input type="text" name="email">
        Pass:<input type="text" name="pw">
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php

 }

}
```

And the index.php:

```
<?php
require_once "model/Autoload.php";

$view = new View();
$view->createLoginUI();
```

In the createLoginUI has a link. The link function is load the registry UI. I made this:

```
public function newSite($view) {

    if(isset($_GET['regist'])) {

    $view->createRegist();

    }

}
```

I call this method in index.php. If I click the "regist" button, it displays both views. I'd like to see only "regist" view. I tried the header(), but I don't know how can I call a method in header and not sure that it will work.

Comment: then don't call `createLoginUI()` on the registration page. you're getting both because you're TELLING php to output both.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to return HTML in a PHP function? (without building the return value as a string)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528445/is-there-any-way-to-return-html-in-a-php-function-without-building-the-return)

Comment: i'm not entirely clear what you're asking, but why aren't you creating a new view before calling createRegist() ?  shouldn't `$view = new View();` occur before that line?

Comment: @johnny - i'm not seeing the similarity between the two questions.  OP isn't asking *how* to return html from PHP.  OP is getting more returned than desired, from my understanding.

Comment: @devlincarnate Won't that question I mentioned show him how to do that?

Comment: @johnny - OP is already returning HTML from PHP.  OP is getting results from two different functions that return HTML.  i believe only one result (one set of HTML) is desired.

Comment: Just make different pages. This approach will just get bloated and ridiculous over time.

Comment: I think you  should use a MVC approach if you want to serve separate views by calling different methods. I think your company's requirement might prefer that.

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
<?php
  class View{


   public function createLoginUI(){
    echo '<html>
          <title></title>
          <head></head>
          <body>
          <form>
              Email:<input type="text" name="mail">
              Pass:<input type="text" name="pass">
              <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"><br>
              <a href="?regist" >Regist</a>

          </form>
          </body>
          </html>';
   }
   .....
   .....
}
```

Comment: I tried it , but always show both view. I tried lot of thing what you wrote here since yesterday , but none of them work fine. I begin give up that.

Comment: @Bbeni remove all the HTML and make straight up echo 'test'; and see what happens.  Do you get both?  Where are you calling them from?