# Including HTML in php return equation?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to add HTML to my php return response which is within an if/else statement,
Basically it looks something like so(I have omitted the top portion) but the if part goes like so...

```
  <?php
      if ($c > 1200) {
     Echo "The blab bla bla, bla blah blah blah" .$c;
  }
  ?>
```

I want to have HTML in the response but I can't find an answer here which would help and relate things for me and my problem.
Any help appreciated here, thanks. Oh and I have not figured out how to mark the answer 'answered' but I will do that, thanks.

Comment: You can put html in quotes: `echo '<p>simple</p>';`

Comment: Yes I understand the underlying premise.  Which is why I now intend to respond to answers.  Of which I  would like to add have all been appreciated and helped me in the past. Good on you!

Comment: What exactly is your issue? Certainly the contents of `$c` will get echoed here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to return HTML in a PHP function? (without building the return value as a string)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528445/is-there-any-way-to-return-html-in-a-php-function-without-building-the-return)

Comment: Well, When I place a <p> tag before the echo statement and a closing </p> tag after the echo statement my ide is throwing an exception.  If I place any HTML around the echo which is itself of course within the if block It spits an exception.

Comment: Trying to make sense of that.

Comment: `echo '<p>' . $c . '</p>';` should work fine as long as you're on a web server.

Comment: I'll try what you suggest workabyte, thanks.

Comment: Ok thanks Jay Blanchard, will check into that as well.  Will work on it and post back in about 1/2 hour, cheers all.

Comment: Figured it out thanks again.  Jay Blanchard answer is what I used, although I also appreciate your here doc reference workabyte.  Ok, you folks are going to have a laugh, how do I vote the correct answer?

Comment: Excellent.  So basically the answer is : use concatenation to add your strings together with your variable.  The concatenation operator in php is the .  The single quotations are wrapped around each HTML tag like so-'<p>'  .  'Thanks again'   .   '</p>'  .  '<p>'  .  $c  .  '</p>';

Answer (score 1):

Excellent. So basically the answer is : use concatenation to add your strings together with your variable. The concatenation operator in php is the `.` The single quotations are wrapped around each HTML tag like

so-

```
 '<p>' . 'Thanks again' . '</p>' . '<p>' . $c . '</p>';
```

Comment: Since the HTML and the string contents are both strings as far as PHP is concerned you only need to concatenate the `$c` like so: `echo '<p>Thanks again</p><p>' . $c . '</p>';` Including the HTML and string contents together will work just the same.